# do wallets like metamask interact with infura.io?

Tags: infura, nethereum, fantom

I want to create my own wallet using nethereum.

Do I need paid service like infura?

Say I want to send money from one fantom address to another.

Do I need some public ethereum or fantom client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently metamask uses an upstream RPC node to read information from the chain as well as broadcast transactions to the chain.

The RPC used is configured per network - when a user adds a new network they are expected to specify an RPC for metamask to use when interacting with that network.

The networks available by default in metamask (Eth, Eth testnets) are all pointing at Infura.

You can let your users specify which RPC they would like to use in the wallet. Most networks provide some public RPC's (which are rate limited, but usually enough for end users).

In future (post `The Merge`) wallets (even browser based ones) will be able to run their own RPC as a light client decreasing the reliance on node operators like infura.

Comment: infura requires API key. Does metamask need API key?